# React.js and ES2015 - Pass a method from parent to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to remove the child element(Note) when a user click the remove button. The remove method is on parent(Board) and I try to pass it to child thru props, but it is not working.

I try to use simple remove, this.remove - not defined remove, or this, this.remove.bind(this) nothing seems to work;location: eachNote(text,i) method

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';




class Note extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {editing: false};

    }

    edit() {
        this.setState({editing: true});
    }

    save() {
        let val = this.refs.newText.value;
        this.setState({editing: false});
    }

    renderNormal(){
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{this.props.children} </p>
                <button type="button" onClick={this.edit.bind(this)}>Edit</button>
                <button type="button" onClick={this.hRemove.bind(this)}>Remove</button>

            </div>
        );
    }

    renderForm(){
        return (
        <div>
            <textarea ref="newText" defaultValue={this.props.children}></textarea>
            <button type="button" onClick={this.save.bind(this)}>Saved</button>
        </div>
    );
    }

    render() {
            if(this.state.editing ==true ) {return this.renderForm();}
            else {return this.renderNormal();}
    }
}

class Board extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {comments: ['icecream','antimoniu','bentrans'] };

    }


    remove(i){
        let arr = this.state.comments;
        arr.splice(i,1);
        this.setState({comments: arr});
    }

     eachNote(text,i) {
        return (<Note key={i} index={i} hRemove={this.remove}>{text}</Note>);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.comments.map(this.eachNote)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Board />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

---

I tried Rafi Ud Daula Refat and Sven (thanks for answers) codes and the below one, but I still received the error:  this is undefined;

in the Parent,  I have:

```
eachNote(text,i) {
    return (<Note key={i} index={i} hRemove={this.remove.bind(i)}>{text}  </Note>);
 }
```

in the Child,  I have:

```
removed(i) {
    this.props.hRemove(i);

}
renderNormal(){
       return (
            <div>
                <p>{this.props.children} </p>
                <button type="button" onClick=     {this.edit.bind(this)}>Edit</button>
               <button type="button" onClick=  {this.removed.bind(this,i)}>Remove</button>

        </div>
    );
}
```

I tried also this.removed.bind(this) and this.removed.bind(i), hRemove={this.remove.bind(i)}, and their combinations not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use one method of parent you should pass the function as a props to the child. and from child you can access it as

> this.props.functionName

Here in your note Component

```
        <button type="button" onClick={this.hRemove.bind(this)}>Remove</button>
```

But note component does not have any method named hRemove. It can be assed through

> this.props.hRemove()

```
        <button type="button" onClick={this.props.hRemove(idorsomething)}>Remove</button>
```

And as the function 'remove' in the parent component has one parameter. So from the Child component note you have pass variable a. then it will work. like

> this.props.hRemove(id)

Comment: I tried the proposed solution I receive an error: this is undefined; I updated my original post

Comment: just remove the bind() on this.props.hRemove().

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the function `remove` as a `hRemove`prop to your `Note`, you can find it in `this.props.hRemove`.

You can also `bind` the `Note` directly to the passed `remove` function:

```
eachNote(text,i) {
    return (<Note key={i} index={i} hRemove={this.remove.bind(i)}>{text}</Note>);
}
```

Then you simply use

```
<button type="button" onClick={this.props.hRemove}>Remove</button>
```

Keep in mind, with ES6 you don't have `this` in your custom render methods, this can be done in several ways: http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html

Comment: I tried the proposed solution I receive an error: this is undefined; I updated my original post